# Most efficient way of randomly choosing a set of distinct integers

Tags: algorithm, random, language-agnostic, combinations

I'm looking for the most efficient algorithm to randomly choose a set of n distinct integers, where all the integers are in some range [0..maxValue].

Constraints:

- maxValue is larger than n, and possibly much larger
- I don't care if the output list is sorted or not
- all integers must be chosen with equal probability

My initial idea was to construct a list of the integers [0..maxValue] then extract n elements at random without replacement. But that seems quite inefficient, especially if maxValue is large.

Any better solutions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Algorithm to select a single, random combination of values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394246/algorithm-to-select-a-single-random-combination-of-values) See the accepted answer for Bob Floyd algorithm, which is tailored specifically for this situation.

Comment: Not really a duplicate, as that question refers to a subset of an arbitrary  set. This is taking a sample from sequential integers, which is a more specific problem (and therefore potentially amenable to better algorithms / more finely optimised approaches)

Comment: I went with a blended approach that selected a different alogorithm based on the size of both n and maxValue, incorporating ideas from Mark, Eyal, Rafe and Rex. Thanks for all the great answers!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For small values of maxValue such that it is reasonable to generate an array of all the integers in memory then you can use a variation of the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher-Yates_shuffle) except only performing the first `n` steps.

---

If `n` is much smaller than `maxValue` and you don't wish to generate the entire array then you can use this algorithm:

1. Keep a sorted list `l` of number picked so far, initially empty.
2. Pick a random number `x` between 0 and `maxValue` - (elements in `l`)
3. For each number in `l` if it smaller than or equal to `x`, add 1 to `x`
4. Add the adjusted value of `x` into the sorted list and repeat.

If `n` is very close to `maxValue` then you can randomly pick the elements that *aren't* in the result and then find the complement of that set.

---

Here is another algorithm that is simpler but has potentially unbounded execution time:

1. Keep a set `s` of element picked so far, initially empty.
2. Pick a number at random between 0 and `maxValue`.
3. If the number is not in `s`, add it to `s`.
4. Go back to step 2 until `s` has `n` elements.

In practice if `n` is small and `maxValue` is large this will be good enough for most purposes.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your algorithm correctly. Assume that maxValue is 1000. If I have `{1,4}` in list and random function return `3`, so I add `1` to it because there is one element that smaller than `3`. Now I got {1,4,4}. Sorry If I misunderstood.

Comment: @tia: he means, `for (l in list) if (l <= x) ++x;`. So after you've incremented `x` once, because "1" is in the list, you'll increment it again, because "4" is in the list, resulting in 5.

Comment: The first approach uses space proportional to maxValue. The second one is O(n^2) time. The third has a reasonable expected running time (O(N Log N), but it is not bounded in the worst case, as you said. See my response, which offers a linear space/time solution in n.

Answer (score 15):

Here is an optimal algorithm, assuming that we are allowed to use hashmaps. It runs in **O(n) time and space** (and not O(maxValue) time, which is too expensive).

It is based on Floyd's random sample algorithm. See my [blog post](http://eyalsch.wordpress.com/2010/04/01/random-sample/) about it for details.
The code is in Java:

```
private static Random rnd = new Random();

public static Set<Integer> randomSample(int max, int n) {
    HashSet<Integer> res = new HashSet<Integer>(n);
    int count = max + 1;
    for (int i = count - n; i < count; i++) {
        Integer item = rnd.nextInt(i + 1);
        if (res.contains(item))
            res.add(i);
        else
            res.add(item);
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Nice article. I do find the idea that in case of collision I can just pick the "max" element (`i` here) counter-intuitive, care to enlighten me with "simple" words ?

Comment: see my [proposed answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32116867/3591273) with strictly `O(n)` time and space algorithm, not requiring hasmaps (which may not be available and hide some complexity issues behind their implementation, e.g fetch time is not `O(1)`). It is based on variation of shuffle, i.e partial shuffling

Comment: @EyalSchneider, yes there is a point there, however even immutable arraylists can be shuffled (they are references). But yes it requires the initial array and not just the size. For point 4. on your post (randomising a stream/offline list, probably very large), see [related question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28990820/iterator-to-produce-unique-random-order)

Comment: @EyalSchneider, the **swaping section** of the blog post is similar solution (partial shuffling), but destructive

Comment: @EyalSchneider, btw working on strictly `O(k)` random combination solution (not requiring array, just size `n`) for my [combinatorics lib Abacus](https://gitub.com/foo123/Abacus)

Comment: I don't understand why you used a HashSet. What value does it add? I think my solution is better http://stackoverflow.com/a/38736104/5810023 -- maybe you have something similar in your blog, but I still don't see why you haven't posted the better ones here.

Comment: @caveman: your approach is correct and it also appears in my blog post (see "Swapping"). However, it has 2 important requirements in order to be applied: The input collection must be random access, and modifiable. 
In this particular case you are not given a collection. Instead, you are given two numbers (n, maxValue). If you try to apply your algorithm you first have to build the array... which leads to O(maxValue) space and time.

Comment: @EyalSchneider thank you! Sorry I missed the maxValue bit! But nonetheless initializing an array up to maxValue is done only *once*! Thus I think must be cheaper than using a HashMap!

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it without generating the full array.

Say I want a randomly selected subset of m items from a set {x1, ..., xn} where m <= n.

Consider element x1.  I add x1 to my subset with probability m/n.

- If I *do* add x1 to my subset then I reduce my problem to selecting (m - 1) items from {x2, ..., xn}.
- If I *don't* add x1 to my subset then I reduce my problem to selecting m items from {x2, ..., xn}.

Lather, rinse, and repeat until m = 0.

This algorithm is O(n) where n is the number of items I have to consider.

I rather imagine there is an O(m) algorithm where at each step you consider how many elements to remove from the "front" of the set of possibilities, but I haven't convinced myself of a good solution and I have to do some work now!

Comment: I really like this idea... especially if it is possible to skip elements at the front to give the right distribution!

Answer (score 2):

If you are selecting `M` elements out of `N`, the strategy changes depending on whether `M` is of the same order as `N` or much less (i.e. less than about N/log N).

If they are similar in size, then you go through each item from `1` to `N`.  You keep track of how many items you've got so far (let's call that `m` items picked out of `n` that you've gone through), and then you take the next number with probability `(M-m)/(N-n)` and discard it otherwise.  You then update `m` and `n` appropriately and continue.  This is a `O(N)` algorithm with low constant cost.

If, on the other hand, `M` is significantly less than `N`, then a resampling strategy is a good one.  Here you will want to sort `M` so you can find them quickly (and that will cost you `O(M log M)` time--stick them into a tree, for example).  Now you pick numbers uniformly from `1` to `N` and insert them into your list.  If you find a collision, pick again.  You will collide about `M/N` of the time (actually, you're integrating from 1/N to M/N), which will require you to pick again (recursively), so you'll expect to take `M/(1-M/N)` selections to complete the process.  Thus, your cost for this algorithm is approximately `O(M*(N/(N-M))*log(M))`.

These are both such simple methods that you can just implement both--assuming you have access to a sorted tree--and pick the one that is appropriate given the fraction of numbers that will be picked.

(Note that picking numbers is symmetric with not picking them, so if `M` is almost equal to `N`, then you can use the resampling strategy, but pick those numbers to *not* include; this can be a win, even if you have to push all almost-`N` numbers around, if your random number generation is expensive.)

Answer (score 1):

My solution is the same as Mark Byers'.  It takes O(n^2) time, hence it's useful when n is much smaller than maxValue.  Here's the implementation in python:

```
def pick(n, maxValue):
    chosen = []
    for i in range(n):
        r = random.randint(0, maxValue - i)
        for e in chosen:
            if e <= r:
                r += 1
            else:
                break;
        bisect.insort(chosen, r)
    return chosen
```

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to use a variation of [shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) or in  other words a partial shuffle.

```c
function random_pick( a, n ) 
{
  N = len(a);
  n = min(n, N);
  picked = array_fill(0, n, 0); backup = array_fill(0, n, 0);
  // partially shuffle the array, and generate unbiased selection simultaneously
  // this is a variation on fisher-yates-knuth shuffle
  for (i=0; i<n; i++) // O(n) times
  { 
    selected = rand( 0, --N ); // unbiased sampling N * N-1 * N-2 * .. * N-n+1
    value = a[ selected ];
    a[ selected ] = a[ N ];
    a[ N ] = value;
    backup[ i ] = selected;
    picked[ i ] = value;
  }
  // restore partially shuffled input array from backup
  // optional step, if needed it can be ignored
  for (i=n-1; i>=0; i--) // O(n) times
  { 
    selected = backup[ i ];
    value = a[ N ];
    a[ N ] = a[ selected ];
    a[ selected ] = value;
    N++;
  }
  return picked;
}
```

**NOTE** the algorithm is strictly `O(n)` in **both time and space**, produces **unbiased selections** (it is a **partial unbiased shuffling**) and **does not need hasmaps** (which may not be available and/or usualy hide a complexity behind their implementation, e.g fetch time is not `O(1)`, it might even be `O(n)` in worst case)

adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32035566/efficiently-pick-n-random-elements-from-php-array-without-shuffle/32035986#32035986)

Comment: The space is clearly not **O(n)** as you claim. It's rather **O(N)**. Plus your algorithm is not uniformly selecting numbers. This is due to the fact that you use `rand(0, --N)`. This is a problem, for example, the number `a[N-1]` can only be chosen when `i = 0` (but not when `i != 0`).  Also I don't see why you use two arrays `picked` and `backup`. Seems redundant. Check my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38736104/5810023

Comment: @caveman convince yourself that the algorithm is strictly O(n) in both time and space. As for being unbiased and indeed selecting uniformly check the original link on Fisher-Yates shuffle algorithm. This is simply a partial shuffle to generate only n elements, instead of N.

Answer (score 0):

Linear congruential generator modulo maxValue+1. I'm sure I've written this answer before, but I can't find it...

Comment: Surely that doesn't guarantee distinct values?

Comment: With suitably chosen parameters, a LCG modulo m cycles through all values in [0, m-1]. This is one reason they're used as PRNGs (they eventually cycle through all possible output values and are therefore "uniform"). The Wikipedia page lists the necessary conditions (insert usual Wikipedia caveat): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** I am wrong. The output of this is not uniformly distributed. Details on why are [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/228263/100507).

---

I think this algorithm below is *optimum*. I.e. you cannot get better performance than this.

For choosing **n** numbers out of **m** numbers, the best offered algorithm so far is presented below. Its worst run time complexity is **O(n)**, and needs only a single array to store the original numbers. It partially shuffles the first **n** elements from the original array, and then you pick those first **n** shuffled numbers as your solution.

This is also a fully working C program. What you find is:

- Function `getrand`: This is just a PRNG that returns a number from `0` up to `upto`.
- Function `randselect`: This is the function that randmoly chooses **n** unique numbers out of **m** many numbers. This is what this question is about.
- Function `main`: This is only to demonstrate a use for other functions, so that you could compile it into a program and have fun.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int getrand(int upto) {
    long int r;
    do {
        r = rand();
    } while (r > upto);
    return r;
}

void randselect(int *all, int end, int select) {
    int upto = RAND_MAX - (RAND_MAX % end);
    int binwidth = upto / end;

    int c;
    for (c = 0; c < select; c++) {
        /* randomly choose some bin */
        int bin = getrand(upto)/binwidth;

        /* swap c with bin */
        int tmp = all[c];
        all[c] = all[bin];
        all[bin] = tmp;
    }
}

int main() {
    int end = 1000;
    int select = 5;

    /* initialize all numbers up to end */
    int *all = malloc(end * sizeof(int));
    int c;
    for (c = 0; c < end; c++) {
        all[c] = c;
    }

    /* select select unique numbers randomly */
    srand(0);
    randselect(all, end, select);
    for (c = 0; c < select; c++) printf("%d ", all[c]);
    putchar('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

[Here](https://bpaste.net/show/d799b1973bd6) is the output of an example code where I randomly output **4** permutations out of a pool of **8** numbers for 100,000,000 many times. Then I use those many permutations to compute the probability of having each unique permutation occur. I then sort them by this probability. You notice that the numbers are fairly close, which I think means that it is uniformly distributed. The theoretical probability should be **1/1680 = 0.000595238095238095**. Note how the empirical test is close to the theoretical one.

Comment: The input in this question isn't an array. This changes the time complexities of your approach completely. Due to the array initialization, it runs in O(maxValue) time and space, which isn't optimal.

Comment: But the array initialization part is out of the scope for the random permutation selection. The random permutation part doesn't care about how many elements exist in the array (maxValue), instead it only cares about total number of bits that you want to choose, only.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the maxValue bit. But here is the thing: the array allocation up to maxValue value is done only once, and is not repeated during the run time. I think this makes my approach faster than your approach with hashmaps. So while allocating an array up to maxValue has a cost, but this cost is small and is done only once. Whereas your use of hashmap has a cost that keeps reoccurring during the time time of your application.

Comment: Yes, your approach is faster in worst case time complexity (assuming a single array initialization), but it does it in the expense of space complexity - O(maxValue). It becomes impractical when maxValue becomes large.

Comment: I agree. Btw any thoughts on whether my method is uniformly distributed across the permutations that it generates?