# Generate N positive integers within a range adding up to a total in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, random, range

I have seen other posts addressing similar problem. I know how to generate N positive integers. I also know how to restrict the sum of randomly generated integers. The only problem is satisfying the condition that none of the N values fall out of the specified range.

e.g. `generate_ints(n, total, low, high)` should generate n value array such that each value is between low and high and the sum adds up to the total. Any pointers/ help would be greatly appreciated.

e.g.`generate_ints(4, 40, 4, 15)` should generate something like

```
[7,10,13,10]
```

I don't care if the numbers are repeated, as long as they are not highly skewed. I am using `np.randon.randint(5,15,n)` to select the integer.

So far, I have tried the following, but it doesn't work -

```
import numpy as np 
import random 
from random import uniform as rand 

total=50 
n=10 
low=2 
high=15 
result=[] 
m=0 
nobs=1 
while nobs <= n: 
    if m >= (total - low): 
        last_num= total -new_tot 
        result.append(last_num) 
    else: 
        next_num=np.random.randint(low,high,1) 
        new_tot = sum(result) + next_num 
        result.append(next_num) 
        m=new_tot 
    nobs +=1 

print result 
print sum(result)
```

Thanks again.

Comment: added my code to the question. thanks@idjaw

Comment: "As far as they are not highly skewed". I think that is impossible to implement unless you make that precise.

Comment: Ideal would be a uniform distribution.

Comment: That's a nice ideal, but unless you can specify how, the question is really too broad.

Comment: @tripleee I consider the description sufficient. Uniform means in this case: from all feasible solutions (n numbers added within these ranges equal to the target); sample one uniformly. (That's of course not the approach to pursue in practice)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

def sampler(samples, sum_to , range_list):
    assert range_list[0]<range_list[1], "Range should be a list, the first element of which is smaller than the second"
    arr = np.random.rand(samples)
    sum_arr = sum(arr)

    new_arr = np.array([int((item/sum_arr)*sum_to) if (int((item/sum_arr)*sum_to)>range_list[0]and int((item/sum_arr)*sum_to)<range_list[1]) \
                            else np.random.choice(range(range_list[0],range_list[1]+1)) for item in arr])
    difference = sum(new_arr) - sum_to
    while difference != 0:
        if difference < 0 :
                for idx in np.random.choice(range(len(new_arr)),abs(difference)):
                    if new_arr[idx] != range_list[1] :
                        new_arr[idx] +=  1

        if difference > 0:
                for idx in np.random.choice(range(len(new_arr)), abs(difference)):
                    if new_arr[idx] != 0 and new_arr[idx] != range_list[0] :
                        new_arr[idx] -= 1
        difference = sum(new_arr) - sum_to
    return new_arr

new_arr = sampler (2872,30000,[5,15])
print "Generated random array is :"
print new_arr
print "Length of array:", len(new_arr)
print "Max of array: ", max(new_arr)
print "min of array: ", min(new_arr)
print "and it sums up to %d" %sum(new_arr)
```

result :

```
Generated random array is :
[ 9 10  9 ...,  6 15 11]
Length of array: 2872
Max of array:  15
min of array:  5
and it sums up to 30000
```

Comment: Ran it 1000 times and got results from 177 to 183

Comment: @FranciscoCouzo fixed

Comment: This approach is not uniform (has some bias; in my opinion) but might be enough for some tasks (and is fast compared to rejection-sampling).

Comment: @sumoka If the answer addresses your question accept it by clicking on the checkmark of that answer ([like here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/QpogP.png)) so that others notice it will work in the first look.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work on larger population e.g.  low=5 , high=15, n=2872, total=30000. I see it generates random integers but not within the bounds.

Comment: @sumoka give me numbers, how many sample sum up to how much ?

Comment: 2872 samples that should sum up to 30000 with values between 5 & 15. I wrote it as a function.. Maybe I messed up something while writing it as a function.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the specifications correctly, you wish to randomly generate restricted integer [compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)) such that each possible composition has an equal likelihood of being chosen.

We can adapt [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2163753) to the problem of uniformly generating a random integer [*partition*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) to solve this problem exactly for small input values. We simply need a way to count restricted k-compositions. There's a recursive formulation in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1360502) on Mathematics to a related problem, but it turns out that there is a more explicit formula mentioned as part of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1594585) that uses binomial coefficients. Here's a implementation in pure Python:

```
import functools
import random

@functools.lru_cache(1 << 10)
def C1(n, k, a, b):
    "Counts the compositions of `n` into `k` parts bounded by `a` and `b`" 
    return C2(n - k*(a - 1), k, b - (a - 1))

def C2(n, k, b):
    "Computes C(n, k, 1, b) using binomial coefficients"
    total = 0
    sign = +1

    for i in range(0, k + 1):
        total += sign * choose(k, i) * choose(n - i*b - 1, k - 1)
        sign = -sign

    return total

def choose(n, k):
    "Computes the binomial coefficient of (n, k)"
    if k < 0 or k > n:
        return 0

    if k == 0 or k == n:
        return 1

    k = min(k, n - k)
    c = 1

    for i in range(k):
        c = c * (n - i) // (i + 1)

    return c

def check_pre_and_post_conditions(f):
    def wrapper(n, k, a, b):
        assert 1 <= k <= n, (n, k)
        assert 1 <= a <= b <= n, (n, a, b)
        assert k*a <= n <= k*b, (n, k, a, b)

        comp = f(n, k, a, b)

        assert len(comp) == k, (len(comp), k, comp)
        assert sum(comp) == n, (sum(comp), n, comp)
        assert all(a <= x <= b for x in comp), (a, b, comp)

        return comp
    return functools.wraps(f)(wrapper)

@check_pre_and_post_conditions
def random_restricted_composition(n, k, a, b):
    "Produces a random composition of `n` into `k` parts bounded by `a` and `b`"
    total = C1(n, k, a, b)
    which = random.randrange(total)
    comp = []

    while k:
        for x in range(a, min(b, n) + 1):
            count = C1(n - x, k - 1, a, b)

            if count > which:
                break

            which -= count

        comp.append(x)
        n -= x
        k -= 1

    return comp
```

To select a random composition, we simply generate a random index smaller than the total number of possible compositions, and then construct the `i-th` lexicographic composition (see the linked questions for explanations of the recurrence relations used). This should produce all possible outcomes with equal probability.

**However**, because `C1(n, k, a, b)` grows exponentially, this method is pretty slow for large values of `n` and `k`. For large values, an approximate solution will serve you better.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my attempt which I will explain.

```
import numpy as np


def generate_ints(n, total, low, high):
    begin = 0
    randys = []
    correctTotal = False
    while correctTotal is False:
        while begin < n:
            r1 = np.random.randint(low, high, 1)
            randys.append(r1)
            begin += 1
        if sum(randys) == total:
            correctTotal = True
        else:
            begin = 0
            del randys[:]
    generated_list = np.array(randys).tolist()
    gen = [g[0] for g in generated_list]
    return gen


my_list = generate_ints(4, 40, 4, 15)
print "Generated list '{}' with sum {}.".format(my_list, sum(my_list))
```

Inside the function, I've set two constants, `randys` and `begin`. In the inner `while` loop, as long as `begin` is less than `n` it generates `n` random integers between `low` and `high`. If the sum is equivalent to the `total`, exit out of the outer `while` loop, otherwise it needs to reset the constants.

Just returning `randys` will give a list of NumPy `array`s. Using the `tolist()` method, this produces a list instead.

Now we have a list of lists. I've flattened it using a short and sweet list comprehension. Finally `return` that list and output as desired.

HTH.

Comment: The code is not that concise (e.g. using a loop for drawing multiple random numbers; it's provided out of the box) and this approach is infeasible for large n or troublesome bounds, but this approach is bias-free and if output is generated, it's uniform. The general algorithmic framework used is called **rejection-sampling**.

Comment: @sascha That's interesting, I didn't know that was provided! Sorry if my answer turned out to be infeasible, I'm frankly have very little knowledge of numpy but I'll look into this more

Comment: Actually, i upvoted it because of the approach (it's not an easy problem). Not sure who downvoted for which reasons (although i did not test your code).

Comment: Thanks, I agree it's not an easy problem especially generating data with a certain distribution. I was looking for a way to make the "total" a function of "n" and the bounds "low" and "high" . Both these solutions solve that problem. I am not 100% clear about how it works but I'll decode line by line. Thanks again.